# How to make a warped texture look smoother?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, export, antialiasing

I'm trying to warp (using `warp`) some texture into a rectangle in MATLAB and then view it in different angles (with `view`). The problem is the texture is rendered in very poor way (aliasing in lines of output image).

I searched on MATLAB community but it seems like no one tried it before.

```
imgRGB = imread('0.png');
h = warp(imgRGB);
view([-10 60]);
axis off;
saveas (h,"0_w_0.png");
```

Here is the input:
[image: input]

And this is unexpected output (sawwy/aliased/not smooth):
[image: output]

Comment: What if you resize (enlarge) it before warping? Would that not help? Please define **quantitatively** what you considered "smoother". _To me_ it looks pretty smooth (if I step back and squint).

Comment: I have retagged your question and added the [tag:export] tag (assuming, based on your `saveas` at the end, that you're interested in exporting it). If your intention is only to **display** it in MATLAB, please remove this tag and consider replacing it with something else, like [tag:projection] or [tag:perspectivecamera].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aliasing you're seeing is just a matter of resolution. If you export it at a higher resolution, the result is much smoother:

[image]

The code I used for that is:

```matlab
im = imread('https://i.imgur.com/ul6JvA1.png');
figure(); imshow(imbinarize(im(:,:,1)));
view([-10 60]);
axis off;
export_fig('E:\F1.png','-png','-m4');
```

Where [`export_fig`](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig//) is a well-known 3<sup>rd</sup> party utility.

Alternatively, you can try using some vectoric format (as opposed to `.png`) to represent barcodes such as this. For example, your image can be converted to `SVG` by [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), which would not only facilitate rasterized export at whichever resolution you want, but will also allow you to add various interesting effects like [perspective](http://goinkscape.com/using-perspective-for-3d-in-inkscape/):

[image]

One possible vectoric representation of your original image is this (save as `.svg` to view):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 118.7979125976562 62.97083282470703"
   height="62.97083282470703mm"
   width="118.7979125976562mm">
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-38.07102599666313,-119.7266511900346)">
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:0.2645833492"
       d="M 38.07102599666313,119.7266511900346 H 38.60019265973527 39.12935932280744 V 182.6974854581405 H 38.60019265973527 38.07102599666313 Z M 40.45227598048774,119.7266511900346 H 41.11373430932791 41.77519263816808 V 182.6974854581405 H 41.11373430932791 40.45227598048774 Z M 44.15644262199269,119.7266511900346 H 45.47935927967302 46.80227593735335 V 182.6974854581405 H 45.47935927967302 44.15644262199269 Z M 49.18352592117798,119.7266511900346 H 49.84498425001813 50.50644257885829 V 182.6974854581405 H 49.84498425001813 49.18352592117798 Z M 54.21060922036324,119.7266511900346 H 54.87206754920345 55.53352587804359 V 182.6974854581405 H 54.87206754920345 54.21060922036324 Z M 57.91477586186818,119.7266511900346 H 58.57623419070835 59.23769251954853 V 182.6974854581405 H 58.57623419070835 57.91477586186818 Z M 60.56060917722884,119.7266511900346 H 61.75123416914117 62.94185916105347 V 182.6974854581405 H 61.75123416914117 60.56060917722884 Z M 65.32310914487804,119.7266511900346 H 66.64602580255835 67.96894246023873 V 182.6974854581405 H 66.64602580255835 65.32310914487804 Z M 69.29185911791904,119.7266511900346 H 71.14394243867153 72.996025759424 V 182.6974854581405 H 71.14394243867153 69.29185911791904 Z M 74.31894241710435,119.7266511900346 H 75.50956740901662 76.70019240092894 V 182.6974854581405 H 75.50956740901662 74.31894241710435 Z M 81.72727570011423,119.7266511900346 H 82.3887340289544 83.05019235779457 V 182.6974854581405 H 82.3887340289544 81.72727570011423 Z M 84.10852568393883,119.7266511900346 H 84.76998401277899 85.43144234161917 V 182.6974854581405 H 84.76998401277899 84.10852568393883 Z M 86.75435899929945,119.7266511900346 H 87.41581732813966 88.07727565697983 V 182.6974854581405 H 87.41581732813966 86.75435899929945 Z M 89.1356089831241,119.7266511900346 H 91.64915063271674 94.16269228230936 V 182.6974854581405 H 91.64915063271674 89.1356089831241 Z M 95.48560893998973,119.7266511900346 H 96.14706726882988 96.80852559767004 V 182.6974854581405 H 96.14706726882988 95.48560893998973 Z M 97.8668589238143,119.7266511900346 H 98.52831725265446 99.18977558149467 V 182.6974854581405 H 98.52831725265446 97.8668589238143 Z M 100.5126922391749,119.7266511900346 H 101.0418589022471 101.5710255653193 V 182.6974854581405 H 101.0418589022471 100.5126922391749 Z M 106.5981088645045,119.7266511900346 H 107.2595671933446 107.9210255221849 V 182.6974854581405 H 107.2595671933446 106.5981088645045 Z M 109.2439421798652,119.7266511900346 H 111.0960255006177 112.9481088213702 V 182.6974854581405 H 111.0960255006177 109.2439421798652 Z M 114.2710254790504,119.7266511900346 H 114.8001921421225 115.3293588051948 V 182.6974854581405 H 114.8001921421225 114.2710254790504 Z M 117.9751921205555,119.7266511900346 H 118.6366504493956 119.2981087782358 V 182.6974854581405 H 118.6366504493956 117.9751921205555 Z M 121.6793587620604,119.7266511900346 H 122.3408170909006 123.0022754197407 V 182.6974854581405 H 122.3408170909006 121.6793587620604 Z M 126.7064420612457,119.7266511900346 H 127.3679003900858 128.0293587189261 V 182.6974854581405 H 127.3679003900858 126.7064420612457 Z M 129.0876920450703,119.7266511900346 H 129.7491503739106 130.4106087027507 V 182.6974854581405 H 129.7491503739106 129.0876920450703 Z M 135.4376920019359,119.7266511900346 H 136.0991503307761 136.7606086596162 V 182.6974854581405 H 136.0991503307761 135.4376920019359 Z M 141.7876919588016,119.7266511900346 H 142.3168586218738 142.8460252849458 V 182.6974854581405 H 142.3168586218738 141.7876919588016 Z M 144.1689419426262,119.7266511900346 H 146.0210252633786 147.8731085841312 V 182.6974854581405 H 146.0210252633786 144.1689419426262 Z M 149.1960252418115,119.7266511900346 H 149.8574835706516 150.5189418994917 V 182.6974854581405 H 149.8574835706516 149.1960252418115 Z M 152.9001918833163,119.7266511900346 H 153.5616502121566 154.2231085409967 V 182.6974854581405 H 153.5616502121566 152.9001918833163 Z M 155.5460251986771,119.7266511900346 H 156.2074835275173 156.8689418563574 V 182.6974854581405 H 156.2074835275173 155.5460251986771 Z"
  </g>
</svg>
```